# Updated Create-React-App no longer builds

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, uglifyjs

Something interesting happened. I added some libraries (material ui) which forced me to update my 16.3 version of react to hooks (16.8) but unfortunately due a package not supporting react-scripts 2.x I had to stick with `react-scripts: 1.1.0` and everything was still running fine with `npm run start` but now when I try to build with `npm run build` I get a UglifyJS error: `maxium call stack size exceeded`.

I tried removing/reinstalling node_modules and it didn't help.

I searched all the other topics and unfortunately none of them seemed to match my situation as I have not touched Babel, webpack, or ejected.

Note: I have NOT ejected the Create-React-App.

**TERMINAL ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/main.5a18352c.js from UglifyJs
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at compiler.run (/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:128:23)
    at emitRecords.err (/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:269:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:375:38)
    at emitAssets.err (/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:262:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at next (/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:220:14)
    at /Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/sw-precache-webpack-plugin/lib/index.js:98:18
```

Here is error log from the npm run build (I changed some sensitive info)

**debug.log (npm run build):**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v10.18.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w~prebuild: mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w
6 info lifecycle mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w~build: mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w
7 verbose lifecycle mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w~build: PATH: /Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer/node_modules/.bin:/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin:/Users/mike/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin:/Users/mike/google-cloud-sdk/bin
9 verbose lifecycle mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w~build: CWD: /Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer
10 silly lifecycle mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build && rm build/static/js/*.map' ]
11 silly lifecycle mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w build: `react-scripts build && rm build/static/js/*.map`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w
15 verbose cwd /Users/mike/Documents/Websites/mySite/viewer
16 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin/node" "/Users/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.18.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w build: `react-scripts build && rm build/static/js/*.map`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the mySite-Web-Application@1.2.10-w build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Mysite-Web-Application",
  "version": "1.2.10w",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://www.mysite.ca/app/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.7.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "default-passive-events": "^1.0.10",
    "dompurify": "^1.0.11",
    "exif-js": "^2.3.0",
    "firebase": "^7.2.2",
    "firebase-auto-ids": "^1.1.0",
    "hammer-touchemulator": "0.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.11.2",
    "konva": "^4.0.16",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.12.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.2.228",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^9.0.2",
    "react-collapse": "^5.0.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.8.18",
    "react-konva": "^16.10.1-0",
    "react-pdf": "^2.5.3",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^3.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "tesseract.js": "^1.0.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && rm build/static/js/*.map",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome version",
      "last 2 firefox version",
      "last 2 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not know if you could, but I recommend you to update the react-scripts to the latest version(3.3.0). Probably this will fix your problem.

Comment: That did fix the issue. Unfortunately I'm going to have to refactor a lot of my code to use new dependencies in some spots.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `rm -rf node_modules` in the root folder and `npm install` after

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was a icon i had added in a component, with @material-ui/icons. When i removed it, i could build again, but i don't found the solution too.

Comment: If you have also faced this problem and you are also looking for a solution then please consider upvoting the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hi Manish! Thank you for the guidance! I did a upvote in the question now. When i answered i tried to comment in the question but my pontuation don't permit. Anyway, in the answer I explained that the problem may be in the icons, as was my case. I hope I have helped in some way.

Comment: I add the same issue. I was using the material ui icon "ArrowForwardIos " removing it, the issue disappeared! still unsure how that is possible

Comment: found the issue. I was importing the icon
import {ArrowForwardIos} from "@material-ui/icons";
instead of
import ArrowForwardIos from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos";

Answer (score -1):

I had some issues with my build as well. Whist checking around in the community for solutions, I came across this repository:

[A Frontend build config generator](https://createapp.dev/)

**[TLTR;](https://github.com/jakoblind) Basically its a boilerplate that can get up and going quickly!**

SO% to the developer being the c  - https://github.com/jakoblind.